# Why doesn't this jQuery blur() work?

Tags: jquery, blur

Here's the code:

```
$("#textBox").focus(function() {
  $("#textBox").replaceWith('<textarea id="textBox">' + $(this).val() +'</textarea>');
});

$("#textBox").blur(function() {
    $("#textBox").replaceWith('<input type="text" class="questionInput" value="' + $(this).val() + '" id="textBox">');
});

<input name="input1" class="questionInput" id="textBox" type="text">
```

The focus function works, but the blur function does not work. I've already tried a simplier function on blur like alert.

Comment: Ugh, don't use string concatenation to set the value. Especially not without proper escaping. Better use `.val(..)` to set the value.

Comment: How does it not work?  What is happening?  Do you get an error?  What is the expected result and what result are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the live, because you are replacing the current element, which has no blur bound to it.

So try this:

```
$("#textBox").live("focus",function() {

    $("#textBox").replaceWith('<textarea id="textBox">' + $(this).val() +'</textarea>');

});

$("#textBox").live("blur", function() {

    $("#textBox").replaceWith('<input type="text" class="questionInput" value="' + $(this).val() + '" id="textBox">');

});

<input name="input1" class="questionInput" id="textBox" type="text">
```

Comment: I had to add $("input#textBox") and $("textarea#textBox") and it did work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach "blur" when replacing your element with a new one:

```
$("#textBox").focus(function() {
  $("#textBox").replaceWith('<textarea id="textBox">' + $(this).val() +'</textarea>');
  $("#textBox").blur(function() {
     // Do something on blur
});
```

Once you replace the element, you remove the listener too. To overcome this, you attach a listener to the parent element of your form element and just change the content of this parent (listener is on parent so it will stay even when you change what is inside).